# Convert value in a Python dictionary to an int

Tags: python, dictionary, type-conversion

I have a dictionary where:

```
dict['A']='37.0'
```

I want to convert dict['A'] to int.

When I'm trying to write int(dict['A']) the error I get is:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '37.0'
```

When I am converting it to float `float(dict['A'])` - there is no problem.

The only way I managed to convert it to a int is `int(round(float(dict['A'])))` - which is very ugly.

Is there a better way?

Comment: `int('37.0'.split('.')[0])` or `int('37.0'.rstrip('.0'))`

Comment: Well, the input is in fact a float, so it should be converted to a float first. Then if you want to round it or not is up to you. So no, `int(round(float(dict['A'])))` should be the best option (if you want to round, in case you have other numbers with other decimals).

Comment: or just `int(float('123.0'))` if you don't care about fraction

Comment: There are various ways, try `timeit`. According to my quick test `int(float('37.0'))` is the fastest.